# Is it possible to read from a PostGIS geospatial index after filtering on un-indexed columns?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Is it possible to coerce the Postgres planner to filter a results set based on a sequential scan of scalar values, and only then perform a GIS function/comparison based on a spatial index? My production use-case is a bit more complicated, but this example illustrates my goal:

Create a table with a geography column and index on that column:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
id SERIAL,
min INTEGER,
max INTEGER,
active BOOLEAN,
geo GEOGRAPHY(Polygon,4326) );

CREATE INDEX test_table_gidx ON test_table USING gist (geo);
```

I seeded the table with 6000 records, using non-trivial polygon geometries (~10k vertices each).

Performing a simple select based on `min` and `max` takes on the order of milliseconds.

```
geotest=> SELECT count(*) FROM test_table t WHERE t.min <= 50 AND t.max >= 50 ;
 count 
-------
  4000
(1 row)

Time: 3.066 ms
```

An `ST_Intersects` query against the `geo` column takes around 10 seconds with my hardware and configuration.

```
geotest=> SELECT count(*) FROM test_table t WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geo, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-104.70348 38.6661)'));
 count 
-------
  1000
(1 row)

Time: 11051.466 ms
```

Combining the `WHERE` clauses, the query still runs in the time scale of the geometry-only query.

```
geotest=> SELECT count(*) FROM test_table t WHERE  t.min <= 50 AND t.max >= 50 AND ST_Intersects(t.geo, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-104.70348 38.6661)'));
 count 
-------
  1000
(1 row)

Time: 11072.337 ms
```

If it's helpful, here's how the planner is approaching the combined query:

```
geotest=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM test_table t WHERE  t.min <= 50 AND t.max >= 50 AND ST_Intersects(t.geo, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-104.70348 38.6661)'));
                                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=8.43..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10962.332..10962.333 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using test_table_gidx on test_table t  (cost=0.15..8.42 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=8.199..10961.612 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (geo && '0101000020E6100000F758FAD0052D5AC0CCEEC9C342554340'::geography)
         Filter: ((min <= 50) AND (max >= 50) AND (_st_distance(geo, '0101000020E6100000F758FAD0052D5AC0CCEEC9C342554340'::geography, '0'::double precision, false) < '1e-05'::double precision))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1000
 Planning time: 0.260 ms
 Execution time: 10962.606 ms
```

Is there a way to only perform the `ST_Intersects` comparison for records matching the `min`/`max` filter of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Flag this question to be migrated to either [gis.se] or [dba.se] please. This is certainly not the place for it. I would prefer [dba.se].

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE as an optimization fence.

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM test_table t
  WHERE t.min <= 50 AND t.max >= 50
)
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN test_table AS t2
ON t2.id=t1.id
  AND ST_Intersects(
    t2.geom,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-104.70348, 38.6661),4326)
  );
```

Comment: I encountered a syntax error as written. Changing to the following actually slowed the result down by a factor of 3: `WITH t1 AS (SELECT id FROM test_table t WHERE t.min <= 50 AND t.max >= 50)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table t2 JOIN t1 on t2.id = t1.id
WHERE ST_Intersects( t2.geo, GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-104.960175 39.732051)') );` - did I screw something up?